# node js don't sends http request immediately

Tags: node.js

i have simple server and cilent on node.js:
client:

```
var TestHost = 'localhost';
makehttprequest('o1','n1');
t = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
    t = t + i;
};
makehttprequest('o2', 'n2');
function makehttprequest(OldID, NewID) {
    options = {
        host: TestHost,
        path: '/?OldID='+OldID+'&NewID='+NewID,
        port: 4444
    };
    console.log('sending http get');
    http = require('http');
    http.request(options).end();
    console.log('http request was sent');
```

}
    }

server:

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");

function onRequest(request, response) {
    console.log('onRequest');
    request.setEncoding("utf8");

    var strOldID = url.parse(request.url, true).query.OldID;
    var strNewID = url.parse(request.url, true).query.NewID;
    var body = '';

    if ((strOldID !== undefined)&&(strNewID !== undefined)){

        body+='answer for '+strNewID + strOldID;
        console.log(body);
    }else {
        body+='err';
    }
    response.end();
}

function makeuserresponse(response, body) {
    response.writeHead(200, {
        "Content-Type": "text/html"
    });
    response.write(body);
    response.end();
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(4444);
```

In that case server recieves both request at the same time, after second request. I don't understand why that happens. Why node.js not make first request immediatly?

I don't care are this request will be sync or async, I just whant to first request be sending immediatly after call.

I whant see this:Client sends first request, then do some long work, then sends second request. But i see this: client actually don't send first request, he sends both request after that long work.In console after first request I see: http request was sent, but actually it was not sent. It will be sent after all work is done

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking.  Please explain in more detail what you observe and what you expect.

Comment: Multi-line code is unreadable in comments.  If you want to show us more info that includes code, then use the "edit" link to add it to the end of your question and post a comment indicating what you added.  Also, add your first comment to your question itself to clarify it.  People should be able to read the question by itself without reading comments and know everything you are asking.

Comment: P.S.  All  your variables in `makehttprequest()` should be declared with `var` so they aren't implicit globals that may conflict with each other.

Comment: You should read up on how the Node event loop works.

Answer (score 0):

solve problem with use of child_process.fork:
added new file requestsender.js:

```
var AdmHost = 'localhost';

function send_request(OldID, NewID) {
    var options = {
        host: AdmHost,
        path: '/?OldID=' + OldID + '&NewID=' + NewID,
        port: 4444
    };

    var http = require('http');
    http.request(options).end();
}

process.on('message', function(msg) {
    if (msg.type == 'sendrequest') {
        if ((msg.OldID !== undefined) && (msg.NewID !== undefined)) {
            send_request(msg.OldID, msg.NewID);
        }
    }
});
```

and in client.js make this:

```
var sender = require('child_process').fork(__dirname + '/requestsender.js');
send_request('o1', 'n1');
require('child_process').execSync("calc");
send_request('o2', 'n2');
sender.disconnect();
function send_request(OldID, NewID) {
    msg = {
        type: 'sendrequest',
        OldID: OldID,
        NewID: NewID
    }
    sender.send(msg);
}
```